# Usar classe php e Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, orientação-a-objetos

bom dia

A dúvida é a seguinte, eu tenho uma classe de "usuario.class.php", onde dentro dela constam meus atributos, e todos os métodos(insert, update, delete, buscacodigo e etc...)

```
    private(){
    ...todos os atributos da classe
    }

    public function insert(){
    ....
    }
    public function delete(){
    ....
    }

        function retUsu($id){
            if(is_null($id)){
                return false;
                }else
             $sqlpID = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE idu_usujport=".$id;
             $con = $this->con->Connect()->prepare($sqlpID);
             $con->execute();
             $usuario = $con->fetch();
             return json_encode($usuario);   
            }
}
```

ai vou retornar buscar essa informação com ajax e retornar em input types "text" do meu formulário. abaixo esta o exemplo.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#sel_usuario').change(function(){
        var id_user = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../usuario.class.php', //só busco a classe usuário, mas não o método, linha onde fica a duvida. 
            method: 'POST', // Default: GET
            data: { idu_usujport: id_user }, // ID do usuário que você vai pegar do combobox
            success: function(response) {
                // Em caso de sucesso pegar os dados retornados pelo Ajax e popular inputs.
                $('#nome').val(response.nome);
                $('#email').val(response.email);
                $('#senha').val(response.senha);
                $('#imagem').val(response.imagem);
            },
            error: function() {
                // Tratar os erros
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Minha dúvida é assim, esta certo a forma que estou indicando minha classe na url:? uma vez que todos os médodos estão juntos numa mesma classe.

Comment: No arquivo `usuario.class.php` há uma instância da classe e um código que tratará devidamente a requisição POST ou há apenas a definição da classe?

Comment: Anderson, na minha classe usuario.class.php só tenho os atributos, e os metodos SQL, insert, update, delete, e select mais nada. Agora o código que tratará as requisições não existem, isso eu coloco no formulário exemplo IF(ISSET($_POST['CADASTRAR'])) ai sim ele executa uma ação e dentro dele eu pegou a ação instanciada exemplo ($usuario->retUsu).